# Cant change the icon images (React)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I don't know what I should do to make images (favorite.svg and favorite-white.sgv) modify every time you click the button. I tried harder, this is hard. I use React.

Every time I click the button I want the image to change from favorite-white.sgv to favorite.sgv (and also favorite.sgv to favorite-white.sgv). I don't know what to do, or if I did something wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css'
import { InstaF4 } from './componentes/card.js';

const usuario = {
  imagemUser: require ('./componentes/img1.jpg'),
  userName: "Caroline"
}

const fotoPrincipal= {
  fotoPrincipal: 'https://picsum.photos/350/290?'
}

const likes = {
  like1: require ('./componentes/icones/favorite-white.svg'),
  like2:require ('./componentes/icones/favorite.svg'),
  comment: require ('./componentes/icones/comment_icon.svg'),
}


class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      likeIcon: false,
      };
  }  

botaoCurtido = () =>{
  const semLike = this.state.likeIcon;
  this.setState ({likeIcon : !this.state.likeIcon})
};

/*botaoCurtido = () =>{
  const curtida = likes.like2
  this.setState ({likeIcon : curtida})
  //console.log ("testei")
};*/

render() {
  let likeIcon="";
  const curtida = likes.like2
  //let iconeCurtido = require ('./componentes/icones/favorite.svg');

  if(this.state.likeIcon === true){
    likeIcon = curtida
    console.log ("testeiiii")
    }

  return (
  <div className="dados">
    <InstaF4
    imagemUser={usuario.imagemUser}
    userName = {usuario.userName}

    fotoPrincipal={fotoPrincipal.fotoPrincipal}

    likeIcon = {likes.like1}
    likeIconLiked = {likes.like2}
    commentIcon = {likes.comment}
    curtida = {this.botaoCurtido}

    />

{likeIcon}
  </div>
   ) 
}

}


export default App;
```

other page

```
import React from 'react';
import './card.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export function InstaF4(props){
return (
        <div className="feed">

            <div className="usuario">
                <img src={props.imagemUser} alt="" className="imgUser"/>
                <p>{props.userName}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="foto">
                <img src = {props.fotoPrincipal} alt="" className="fotoPrincipal"/>
            </div>
            <div className="likes">
                <img src = {props.likeIcon} alt="" className="likewhite" onClick={props.curtida} />
                <img src = {props.commentIcon} alt="" className="iconeComentario"/>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

InstaF4.propTypes = {
    imagemUser: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    userName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fotoPrincipal: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    likeIcon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    commentIcon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    curtida:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
```

I clicked on the button, the fuction was called, but the image dont change.

Comment: use import { ReactComponent as TestImage} from './testimage.svg' to import svg files

Comment: Do u know if there is something wrong with the code?
The images were imported, but dont change with the onClick event.

Comment: Create a state in InstaF4, maybe named 'IsLiked' and assign props.likeIcon. And change <img src = {this.state.IsLiked} alt="" className="likewhite" onClick={this.toggleLike} />

Comment: I will try later, thnks!

Comment: define 'toggleLike' function with the logic to toggle the 'IsLiked' state

Comment: You are setting `likeIcon` to the desired one. But when passing down to `InstaF4`, you do not pass this down. Instead you pass `like1` and `like2`. And inside the component, you always `render` `likeIcon` which is always `like1` since that was passed down. Change your props `likeIcon` from `{likes.like1}` to `likeIcon` in the parent(App)) component. Also while initializing `likeIcon` in the App component initialize to the correct icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing this as props to from your parent `likeIcon ={likes.like1}`, which won't change as it's always static. You need to ensure to pass the proper **like** value via checking the state `this.state.likeIcon`

In the render method of parent component, you are passing **LikeIcon** which is always set to `likes.like1`.

So change that props to reflect the latest icon:

```
likeIcon={this.state.likeIcon ? likes.like2 : likes.like1}
```

See below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="dados">
        <InstaF4
          imagemUser={usuario.imagemUser}
          userName={usuario.userName}
          fotoPrincipal={fotoPrincipal.fotoPrincipal}

          // This should set the likeIcon as per the boolean variable
          likeIcon={this.state.likeIcon ? likes.like2 : likes.like1}

          commentIcon={likes.comment}
          curtida={this.botaoCurtido} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey!! Thank you!! a lot, I will test it soon!

I just dont understand the "?" here likeIcon={this.state.likeIcon ? likes.like2 : likes.like1}